# PostGIS ST_Area with similar geographies producing different results

Tags: postgis, natural-earth

I'm running `ST_Area` on two different NaturalEarth datasets but am getting different results when the geographies are clipped before performing the area calculation.

First, I've loaded the 10m "admin0" dataset (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.zip) into a table named `countries`.

Second, I've loaded the 10m "land" dataset (http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/physical/ne_10m_land.zip) into a table named `land`.

The area calculation is basically the same for both:

```
SELECT sum(ST_Area(geom::geography)) AS area FROM land;
     area     
-----------------
 146826440837593


SELECT sum(ST_Area(geom::geography)) AS area FROM countries;
       area       
-----------------
 146826603523460
```

Examining the data, it appears that both datasets are the same except that the `land` table has one large multipolygon, whereas `countries` has many individual multipolygons (ie one for each country in the world).

The issue arises when I clip both to a latitude of +/-52 degrees, in which case the areas I calculate for each diverge quite a bit. This is the query:

```
SELECT
sum(
  ST_Area(
    ST_Intersection(
      ST_GeomFromEWKT(
        'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-180 -52, -180 52, 180 52, 180 -52, -180 -52))'),
      geom
    )::geography
  )
) AS land_area
FROM
 land;
```

And it produces these results:

```
    land_area       
-----------------
 119910798321370

  countries_area       
-----------------
 106619873643318
```

Any ideas as to why this would be the case? I've also visualised the clipped geometries for both tables and they *appear* the same to me and I don't see the same area differences when I clip to latitudes like +/-80 degrees.

All the geometries appear to be valid before the intersection as well as after the intersection. For example, the following query produces no results:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 countries
WHERE
NOT ST_IsValid(
      ST_Intersection(
        ST_GeomFromEWKT(
          'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-180 -52, -180 52, 180 52, 180 -52, -180 -52))'),
        geom
      )
    );
```

**UPDATE**: If I do the calculation without converting to `geography`, the numbers do not diverge like they do above:

```
    land_area     
------------------
 9942.37708696352

   country_area   
------------------
 9942.38832452307
```

Comment: Natural Earth data can be quite dirty, have you run isvalid and makevalid on them?

Comment: @PaulRamsey - I didn't find anything invalid when checking the original geometries or the geometries post-intersection (updated question). Thanks!

Comment: You might also look at the presence (or not) of vertices, particularly along long, straight lines.

Comment: @mkennedy Could you explain a little more? Once the clip is applied along the +/-52 latitude, there will be long straight lines without vertices. But how would this affect the results of the area calculation?

Comment: Yeah, if there are lines w/ extra vertices, they'll line up differently as great circles than as cartesian lines. You'll looking at the shapes in cartesian and saying "they are the same", but maybe they aren't the same in great circle world...

Comment: Thank you @PaulRamsey and @mkennedy for pointing me in the right direction. With the political boundaries in the `countries` table, this was not as much of a problem but it manifested itself with the `land` table. The answer is to use `ST_Segmentize` to ensure that the great circle lines are correct.

Comment: @bosth what version? The method changed in 2.2.0 to use GeographicLib, which has a higher precision for this calculation.

Comment: @MikeT This was with 2.2.2, but it has to do with user error concerning great circles rather than PostGIS imprecision!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was around calculating the area of a large polygon with straight lines that had been converted to a `geography` type.

Using `ST_Segmentize` will ensure that there are more intermediary segments in the lines that will provide a better representation of the cartesian lines once you are working with `geography`:

```
SELECT
sum(
  ST_Area(
    ST_Segmentize(
      ST_Intersection(
        ST_GeomFromEWKT(
          'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-180 -52, -180 52, 180 52, 180 -52, -180 -52))'),
        geom
      ), 0.1
    )::geography
  )
) AS land_area
FROM
 land;
```

The reason that the `countries` table wasn't affected is that it has political boundaries doing some rudimentary "segmentation" of the long lines.